# How to correctly us .replace function?

Tags: c#, string, function, replace

Trying to use a .replace function to take out the breaks (`<br>` and `</br>`) though having trouble with the code I have been given.

Here is what I am working with.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
var rawStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
var myBuilder = new StringBuilder();
myBuilder.AppendLine("Employee Name : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_DisplayFullName\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Title: " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Title\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Location : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Location\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Department : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Department\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Group: " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Group\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Office Phone : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_IntPhoneNumber\">", "</span>"));
myBuilder.AppendLine("Mobile Phone : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_BusMobile\">", "</span>"));
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.ToString();
```

Though I understand the function should be like so:

```
public string Replace( string oldValue, string newValue )
```

I just dont understand how this works in my code as I dont really have a "string" but I have a string builder.

Any assistance would be huge.

Comment: Just write myBuilder.Replace("old","new");

Comment: If your aim is to parse html and take some stuff out you should consider using [html agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please when showing sample code avoid unknown methods like `Between` - it is not very clear if you have problem with code that is not shown OR that unknown method is problem itself... And if you are using `String.Replace` to avoid [using regex to parse Html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) use proper parser like HtmlAgilityPack instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does all your StringBuilder stuff have to do with removing the breaks? Your string is in the `rawStream` variable (quite badly named) (that's what [`ReadToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readtoend) gives you), so you'd just:

```
rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br>", "");
rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br />");
```

Comment: I'm a rookie with C# so my naming convention is probably far from standard. Let me test your code out - looks like it might be on point.

Comment: It's okay, we've all been there before. :)

Comment: I tested this out and it works if I put it before the myBuilder.AppendLine command stack.

Thanks a ton! This was driving me wild!
Cheers!

Comment: Works!

Im happy! (But this is what worked :

    rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br>", " ");
    rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br />", " ");

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do:

On the one hand, you do assemble your string with a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), however, you eventually convert the contents of that string builder into a [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) when you call `myBuilder.ToString()`. That is where you could invoke [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.ToString().Replace("<br>", "").Replace("</br>", "");
```

Alternatively, `StringBuilder` has a [`Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of its own, so you could invoke that *before* transforming the string builder contents into a string:

```
myBuilder.Replace("<br>", "");
myBuilder.Replace("</br>", "");
```

Note that the latter can alternatively be invoked in a chained fashion, as well, though that is arguably less readable:

```
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.Replace("<br>", "").Replace("</br>", "").ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put it after the `ToString()` call?

```
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.ToString().Replace("string1", "string2");
```

As mentioned in the comments you can also call it on the stringbuilder object itself.

```
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.Replace("string1", "string2").ToString();
```

Comment: Stringbuilder has a replacemthod itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since replace returns string you can chain them

```
rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br>","").Replace("<br/>","").Replace("<br />","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.Replace("<br>", String.Empty).Replace("</br>", String.Empty).ToString();
```

Or

```
var rawStream = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("<br>", String.Empty).Replace("</br>", String.Empty);
```